# react-native equivalent to native event calls like CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK in TelephonyManager

Tags: react-native

I am learning react native and finished the [official react native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html)

What is not clear to me yet is, how to utilize the native features and implement native events like,

1. Listening to an event whether a call has ended or not
2. Opening up a camera and taking a picture
3. Activating GPS and fetch co-ordinates
   ...etc

I do not find any traces of these in the official tutorial link that i have posted earlier. Additionally, at the [end of the tutorial in this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/more-resources.html) it says

> The folks who built the app for Facebook's F8 conference in 2016 also
>   open-sourced the code and wrote up a detailed series of
>   tutorials. This is useful if you want a more in-depth example
>   that's more realistic than most sample apps out there.

But not able to find examples there either.,

Kindly explain why and what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think React native focuses on creating the UI.To access the phone's hardware you'll have to use plugins, check out JS.coach https://js.coach/ and search for what you need for example type camera if you need something to do with the camera.